# Symfony2 - Several fields of several classes in one form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

While reading, please keep in consideration I'm still learning Symfony2, as I'm new to it. I'm a bit stuck into this so I haven't done anything yet - in fact, I come to you exactly to get myself lead to the right place.

I have, as my requirements, to enter student data into a form. The issue is that most of the data is already split into several classes with indirect relationships. A `Person` has one `InformationContainer`, which in turn has several `Role`s and `InformationUnit`s (some information units are mandatory only when certain roles are added). In turn, `Student` is a role and it has several `StudentAntecedent`s (as it can vary yearly), which has a `Representative` (ManyToOne), which is a `Role`. Also, `InformationUnit`s can hold several information such as birthplace, ethnicity, etc.

As you can see, this has several classes in it. But I must add `Person` information, `InformationUnit` information and `StudentAntecedent` information (and not all of them) in one form. I'm aware I could just go ahead and use embedded forms but I have the feeling it could break (`Person` does not associate directly to `InformationUnit`s, for instance). How do I do this?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: You should split your question into two separate questions. If a person has an answer for one of your questions but not the other, she probably won't answer at all.

Comment: For the moment I think I might delete one of them actually. Thanks.